# Business Central (Dynamics) API Filtering is not applying to result set

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-business-central

My API URL is as follows:

```
 https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/tenant/Company('company')/Chart_of_Accounts/?filter=No gt 83000
```

This appears to be correct by their documentation. However, when calling this URL I get the entire result set, which I am not expecting. This URL is constructed on the fly by some very awful SQL (I know the SQL is awful, my question is about why the filter in the API URL isn't working, not why I chose some awful approach), which is (see below).

Now, I don't think the SQL has anything to do with why the filter isn't working, but nothing in the documentation is very helpful outside of me thinking the URL looks correct? This is the first time I've started interacting with the business Central API, so I'm sure there are fun quirks affecting me here.

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    if object_id('tempdb..#groups') is not null drop table #groups;
    if object_id('tempdb..#Nums') is not null drop table #Nums;

    CREATE TABLE #groups
        (
            [Object] VARCHAR(55)
            , [Group] VARCHAR(55)
            , skwill VARCHAR(MAX)
        )
    ;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)
    , @sql2 VARCHAR(MAX)
    , @count INT=1
    , @Max INT
    , @MaxRows INT
    , @BaseUrl VARCHAR(max)
    , @Group VARCHAR(55)
    , @Object VARCHAR(55)
    , @Company VARCHAR(255);

    SET @BaseUrl=(SELECT TOP 1 url FROM [adf].[ActivitySink]);

    SELECT 
        [Object]
        , [URL]
        ,[Group]
        ,[Company] 
        , Row_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Company) AS RowNum
    INTO #Nums
    FROM [adf].[ActivitySink] 
    WHERE[checkpoint] = 1
    ;

    SET @Max=(SELECT MAX(RowNum) FROM #Nums);

    WHILE @Max>=@Count
        BEGIN
            SET @Object=(SELECT [Object] FROM #Nums WHERE RowNum=@Count);
            SET @Group=(SELECT [Group] FROM #Nums WHERE RowNum=@Count);
            SET @Company=(SELECT Company FROM #Nums WHERE RowNum=@Count);

            SET @sql='SELECT @MaxRowss =ISNULL(CAST((SELECT MAX(
            CAST('+CASE 
                WHEN @Object='Vendors' THEN +' RIGHT('
                ELSE +' '
                END+''+
                CASE
                    WHEN @Object='Chart_of_Accounts' THEN 'No'
                    WHEN @Object='Dimension_Set_Entries' THEN 'Dimension_Set_ID'
                    WHEN @Object='G_L_Registers' THEN 'No'
                    WHEN @Object='G_LEntries' THEN 'Entry_No'
                    WHEN @Object='General_Journals' THEN 'Line_No'
                    WHEN @Object='General_Ledger_Entries' THEN 'Entry_No'
                    WHEN @Object='Posted_Approval_Entries' THEN 'Entry_No'
                    WHEN @Object='VendorLedgerEntries' THEN 'Entry_No'
                    WHEN @Object='Vendors' THEN 'No'
                END+' '+CASE 
                    WHEN @Object='Vendors' THEN+', LEN(No)-1)'
                    ELSE +' '
                    END+'AS INT)) FROM '+@Object+' WHERE Company='''+@Group+''') AS VARCHAR(255)), 0);'

                EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@MaxRowss INT out', @MaxRows OUT

                SET @sql2 = @BaseUrl+@Company+'/?filter='+
                CASE
                    WHEN @Object='Chart_of_Accounts' THEN 'No'
                    WHEN @Object='Dimension_Set_Entries' THEN 'Dimension_Set_ID'
                    WHEN @Object='G_L_Registers' THEN 'No'
                    WHEN @Object='G_LEntries' THEN 'Entry_No'
                    WHEN @Object='General_Journals' THEN 'Line_No'
                    WHEN @Object='General_Ledger_Entries' THEN 'Entry_No'
                    WHEN @Object='Posted_Approval_Entries' THEN 'Entry_No'
                    WHEN @Object='VendorLedgerEntries' THEN 'Entry_No'
                    WHEN @Object='Vendors' THEN 'No'
                END+' gt '+CAST(@MaxRows AS VARCHAR(55))

                INSERT INTO #groups ([Object], [Group], Skwill) VALUES (@Object, @Group, @sql2);
                SET @Count=@Count+1
        END

    SELECT * FROM #groups
```

Comment: Have you checked what the URL returns from Postman or some other tool? Some other OData-like services use `$filter=...` instead of `filter=...` , or require `(` `)` brackets around the expression, and field names are generally case-sensitive, so any/all of those could be a factor.

Comment: Yes I did in fact. i think I just realized the problem though - not sure if it matters or not but the filed returns as a string and not a number. Which is kind of stupid because its a number.... sigh. Which means going off of the documentation filtering on this field, a primary key mind you,, is not possible. Microsoft, why you gotta make things stupid :'(